# Apply aspect only on annotated methods using AspectJ(without Spring)

Tags: java, gradle, aop, aspectj

I want to use aspects in a Java that has some resources limitations so I can't use Spring aspects due to it's big memory footprint.

So want I want to do without Spring, is to create a custom annotation and which will trigger an aspect on the annotated methods.

I have some implementation but I can't see the Apect being triggered when the method runs. This is what I have:

**My custom annotation**

```
 @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface MyCustomAnnotation {}
```

**Where the annotation is used**

```
@MyCustomAnnotation
     public void someMethod() {
        System.out.println("Method runnning...");
     }
```

**The aspect I created**

```
@Aspect
public class MyAspect {

    @Pointcut("execution(* *(..))")
    public void callAt() {}

    @Around(("callAt()"))
    public void doSomething(ProceedingJoinPoint point)  {
      point.proceed();
      System.out.println("Aspect is runnning...");
}
```

**The configurations I have in my gradle file**

```
dependencies {
        classpath "gradle.plugin.aspectj:gradle-aspectj:0.1.6"
    }

apply plugin: 'aspectj-gradle'

    compile 'org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.9.1'
    compile 'org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.9.1'
```

I have no idea why the aspect it's not being triggered, I can't see the message from that aspect in my console when the app runs.
 Any idea what I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried something like:

```
@Around("@annotation(mycustomannotation.package.MyCustomAnnotation)")
```

where mycustomannotation.package.MyCustomAnnotation is the interface of the anotation you created

Comment: Yes this fixed the problem but I also added something else that will allow me to avoid a duplicate execution of the aspect. `@Around("execution(* *(..)) && @annotation(spike.HelloAnnotation)")` Also I was not running the GradleTest runner in my IntelliJ, once I enabled it, all worked well. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The aspect is unrelated to your annotation, but I understand you tried the simplest pointcut first.

As your around advice returns `void`, it can only intercept methods also returning `void`. Probably you are trying to intercept methods with other return types, though, I can only speculate because you did not share your target code. Make sure the around advice returns `Object` (or whichever return type your target methods have) and the result of `proceed()` is returned by the advice.

BTW, your decision not to use Spring just because of its "AOP lite" framework Spring AOP was a good one, AspectJ is much more powerful and efficient. It would be crazy to use Spring just for its limited AOP capabilities. I really don't know why people think about Spring AOP first when it comes to AOP in Java, not about AspectJ.

Answer (score 0):

At some point the aspect needs to be "weaved" into the classes so they can run. This can be done at [runtime](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/devguide/ltw-configuration.html#enabling-load-time-weaving) or at [compile](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/devguide/ajc-ref.html) time.

I would in fact suggest you use compile time as I think it significantly simplifies using aspectj (I've used compile time quite successfully for a long time now).

You're just going to need to find and configure the gradle plugin for this (I use maven).